# How to print a substring between two patterns if an offset is provided as an input

Tags: python, string

How can we print a substring that occurs between two patterns? We are also provided an offset of a character in the string as an input to choose which substring needs to be printed.

E.g.

```
string = '<p class="one">A quick brown fox</p><p class="two">Jumps over</p>'
```

The substring that needs to be printed is between the patterns `">` and `</p>`.

If the offset provided is `20` then `A quick brown fox` should be printed.
If the offset provided is `55` then `Jumps over` should be printed, this offset should be received as an input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) : "Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset seems to be taken as a starting point for searching the nearest `">` to the left and `</p>` to the right.

```
<p class="one">A quick brown fox</p><p class="two">Jumps over</p>
                    ^                                  ^
                 offset 20                          offset 55
```

In other words, find the rightmost `">` in the substring from the beginning to the offset, and the leftmost `</p>` in the substring from the offset to the end.

For this, there are the [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and [`rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) string methods.

```
>>> string.rfind('">', 0, 20)
13
>>> string.rfind('">', 0, 55)
49
>>> string.find('</p>', 20)
32
>>> string.find('</p>', 55)
61
```

Now you can use these indices to slice the string. You have to account for the fact that `rfind` returns the index *before* `">`, but you need to slice *after* it, so you have to add its length (2) to the start index of the slice.

```
>>> start = string.rfind('">', 0, 20) + 2
>>> end = string.find('</p>', 0, 20)
>>> string[start:end]
'A quick brown fox'
```

Comment: Thanks .. The offset can be any number between the matching patterns. I'm trying the solution as you mentioned in the comment of the original question

Comment: While i was testing i encountered n error in the `end` value, so changed to `end = string.find('</p>', start)` . Could you please verify that

Comment: That should work as well.